# QML: Using ScrollView leads to incorrect displaying of elements

Tags: qt, scrollview, qml

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 for windows (Qt creator 3.0.1)

I have a custom QML component, it works fine when I'm loading in into rectangle:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
Rectangle {
    id: mainRectangle
    anchors.fill: parent
        Loader {
            anchors.top: parent.top;
            anchors.left: parent.left;
            anchors.right: parent.right;
            id: ld01;
            onLoaded: {
                ld01.visible = true;
                anchors.top = parent.top;
            }
        }
        Loader {
            anchors.top: ld01.bottom;
            anchors.left: parent.left;
            anchors.right: parent.right;
            id: ld02;
            onLoaded: {
                anchors.top = ld01.bottom;
                ld02.visible = true;
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            ld01.setSource("View_item2.qml");
            ld02.setSource("View_item2.qml");
        }
 }
```

But when I'm trying to put it all inside a ScrollView, elements of my component are moved somewhere. What kind of trick I should implement for correct use of ScrollView?

```
ScrollView {
    id: mainTabLayout
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 4
    //here I put a code from above (except imports, of course)
}
```

Component code is below:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: slv_layout
    objectName: "itemColumnLayout"
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.margins: 1
    property int minimal_height: 200
    height: 400
    color: "green"
    MouseArea {
        property bool is_pressed: false
        property int initial_y: 0
        property int proposed_y: 0
        id: resizeStick
        enabled: true
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: 10
        width: parent.width
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: {
            cursorShape = Qt.SizeVerCursor;
        }
        onPressed: {
            is_pressed = true;
            initial_y = mouseY;
        }
        onReleased: {
            is_pressed = false;
        }
        onMouseYChanged: {
            if (is_pressed) {
                proposed_y = slv_layout.height + mouseY - initial_y;
                if (proposed_y >= slv_layout.minimal_height) {
                    slv_layout.height += (mouseY - initial_y);
                    initial_y = mouseY;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: slvTitle
        text: "device name"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 2
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors.top: slvTitle.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.topMargin: 2
        color: "blue"
        Button {
            id: slv_butt_run;
            objectName: "slv_butt_run"
            width: 60
            height: width
            text: "Run"
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.margins: 2
        }
        Button {
            id: slv_butt_settings;
            objectName: "slv_butt_settings"
            width: 60
            height: width
            text: "Settings"
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: slv_butt_run.right
            anchors.margins: 2
        }
        Button {
            id: slv_butt_stop;
            objectName: "slv_butt_stop"
            width: 60
            height: width
            text: "Stop"
            anchors.top: slv_butt_run.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.margins: 2
        }
        Button {
            id: slv_butt_expand;
            objectName: "slv_butt_expand"
            width: 60
            height: width
            text: "Expand"
            anchors.top: slv_butt_settings.bottom
            anchors.left: slv_butt_stop.right
            anchors.margins: 2
        }
        TextArea {
            id: slv_log_area
            anchors.left: slv_butt_expand.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.margins: 3
        }
    }
}
```

How it looks when all is ok:
[image: How it looks when all is ok]
How it looks when not ok:
[image: How it looks when not ok]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug, It work perfectly fine for me. Can you make a minimal example of your issue ?

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots above.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I still don't know, *why* code works as described above. But I have found acceptable  method to solve task other way.

Looks like "put a needle into egg, egg into duck, duck into rabbit":
ScrollView must contain a ListView component which has a corresponding ListModel and a custom component should act as delegate. Only with ListModel I've got correct automatic scrolling and relative emplacement support.

```
ScrollView {
    id: id_scrollView
    anchors.fill: parent
    objectName: "ScrollView"
    frameVisible: true
    highlightOnFocus: true

    style: ScrollViewStyle {
        transientScrollBars: true
        handle: Item {
            implicitWidth: 14
            implicitHeight: 26
            Rectangle {
                color: "#424246"
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.topMargin: 6
                anchors.leftMargin: 4
                anchors.rightMargin: 4
                anchors.bottomMargin: 6
            }
        }
        scrollBarBackground: Item {
            implicitWidth: 14
            implicitHeight: 26
        }
    }

ListView {

    id: id_listView
    objectName: "ListView"
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.rightMargin: 11
    flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    delegate: view_component
    model: id_listModel

    ListModel {
        id :id_listModel
        objectName: "ListModel"
    }

    //delegate: View_item2.Item
    Component {
        id: view_component
        View_item2 {
            objectName: name
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The rabbit / duck / etc => "the Kastchey QML pattern" ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to the ScrollView [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html),

> A ScrollView can be used either to replace a Flickable or decorate an existing Flickable. ... The width and height of the child item will be used to define the size of the content area.

A ScrollView needs to know two width-height pairs: the first one is the width and height used to display the region, and the second one is the width and height of the content. If the area of the content is larger than the display area, the display area will add a scroll bar on it.

In your example:

```
ScrollView {
    id: mainTabLayout
    anchors.fill: parent
    //other properties

    Rectangle {
        id: mainRectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        //...
    }
}
```

The width and height of the content is bound to the display area, making the two areas be in the same size. The width and height of display area is the one in `mainTabLayout`, which is bound to it's parent; and the width and height of the content is the one in `mainRectangle`, which is bound to it's parent, `mainTabLayout`. Therefore the ScrollView cannot work correctly since ScrollView expects the two values are different, not bound together.

To solve your problem, you can explicitly assign width and height to `mainRectangle`. Do not bind the width and height of `mainRectangle` to it's parent using `anchors.fill:parent`.

```
ScrollView {
    id: mainTabLayout
    anchors.fill: parent
    //other properties

    Rectangle {
        id: mainRectangle

        width: 800; height: 800  //not binding to parent.width & height

        //...
    }
}
```

And this can work correctly.

Comment: You're right, your code will work. But this code would not fit when fixed width and height are unacceptable.

Comment: You can forward the width and height of mainRectangle to mainTabLayout using property alias or something else. Just don't binding them to mainTabLayout's width and height.